# No package available of `libc-client-dev` and `libkrb5-dev` in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum

I install the `libc-client-dev` and `libkrb5-dev` in my CentOS 7.2 Server:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: ftp.yzu.edu.tw
 * extras: mirrors.163.com
 * updates: mirrors.163.com
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
No package libc-client-dev available.
No package libkrb5-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

But there says No package available.

---

**EDIT-01**

```
# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Again problems?

Comment: the `libkrb5-dev` is no package.

Comment: @misdeed See my edit-01.

Comment: Try it, please: ``yum -y install krb5-server krb5-libs``, and say me about results!

Comment: @misdeed Oh, this works. why use this works? and is this is the `libkrb5-dev`'s replace?

Comment: ``libkrb5-dev`` is ``krb5-server`` and ``krb5-libs``.

Comment: Do you installed ``libc-client-dev`` by my answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/857541?noredirect=1)? All done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For install `libkrb5-dev`:

**Pre-Requisites:**

```
yum -y install ntp
ntpdate 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org
systemctl start  ntpd.service
systemctl enable ntpd.service
```

**Installing:**

```
yum -y install krb5-server krb5-libs
```

---

[Source](https://gist.github.com/ashrithr/4767927948eca70845db)